# How to fix navigation problem in React Native (TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am creating a login page in react-native where I am creating three pages: Login.js - this is main page where I am importing both components, and the components are  - Form.js and Loginapi.js.
In Form.js all UI parts, like username, password and button and on button click I am calling, Loginapi.js logical script - and after successful login I have to go to the HomeScreen page. But I am getting `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation) '`

I have tried many things to solve this. Normally I am able to navigate to all screens, but here where I am using components, and on successful login response, it's not moving to the next page.

```
// This is the main login page. 

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View,StatusBar} from 'react-native';
import Logo from '../component/Logo';
import Form from '../component/Form';

export default class Login extends Component {

    render() {

        return(

            <View style ={styles.container}>
            <Logo/>
            <Form  navigation = {this.props.navigation} 
/>
            <View style={styles}>
            </View>
            </View>

        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
    },

  });
```

The below code is form.js for IO where I am entering username and password.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {TextInput,Platform,Alert,AsyncStorage, StyleSheet, Text, View,StatusBar,Image,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

import {Login} from '../api/Loginapi'
  export default class Form extends React.Component
  {

    constructor(){
      super()
      this.state={
        username:"",
        password:"",
        postString: "",
      }
    }

    render() {

        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>

    <TextInput   style={styles.inputBox}
     underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
      placeholder="username"
      placeholderTextColor="#000000"
      onChangeText={(username) => this.setState({username})}/>

   <TextInput   style={styles.inputBox}
     underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
      placeholder="password"
      secureTextEntry={true}
      placeholderTextColor="#000000"
      onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}/>

      {/* <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}onPress={() => this.onClickListener('login')}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity> */}

<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}onPress={() => Login(this.state.username,this.state.password,this)}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

</View>
        )
    }
}

const styles =StyleSheet.create({

container :{
    flex :1,
    justifyContent :'center',
    alignItems:'center'
},
inputBox:{
    width:300,
    borderColor: '#48BBEC',
    backgroundColor: '#F8F8FF',
    borderRadius:25,
    paddingHorizontal:16,
    fontSize:16,
    color:'#000000',
    marginVertical:10,

},
button:{
    width:300,
    backgroundColor:'#4169E1',
    borderRadius:25,
    marginVertical:10,
    paddingVertical:16
},

buttonText:{
fontSize:16,
fontWeight:'500',
color:'#ffffff',
textAlign:'center'

}

})

// Below is my script 

export const  Login = (username,password,self) => {

  var postString = ':xxxxxxxx:21:UN#'+username+':PW#'+password+':';
            var l = postString.length + 2;
            var newPostString = l + postString;
            var newL = newPostString.length;
            if (newL !== l) {
              l++;
            }
            postString = l + postString;

            fetch('http://178.128.19.107:8080/iot-server/JnarkUserAPI', {
              method: 'POST',
              body: postString
            })

            .then( (response) => {
              console.log("Posted:" + postString);
             return response.json();
            })

            .then ( (res => {

              try {

              if (res.success == "true") {
                AsyncStorage.setItem('username', res.userName);
                AsyncStorage.setItem('uEmail', res.email);
                AsyncStorage.setItem('uPh', res.phNum);
                AsyncStorage.setItem('uPlevel', res.privLevel);
                AsyncStorage.setItem('uPwd', res.password);

// here I am getting "[TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation')"

                self.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen');
               // this.props.navigation.replace('HomeScreen');
               // this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen');

              }
              else {
                Alert.alert("Alert Incorrect Credentials");

              }
            } catch (error) {
              console.log("hello",error);
              // Error saving data
            }

            } )  )
          }
```

I expect from my Loginapi.js page, to go to HomeScreen.js page.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should check if the navigation library you are using is properly installed. Are you using [*react-navigation*](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation), [*react-native-router-flux*](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux), ...?

In addition, I think you should post your routes script declaration too so we can help you. Otherwise we can't know what methods you can use to navigate through screens.

Comment: Could you please have a look on the code once.. Please

Comment: Sure, I'm taking a look but as I told you I would need you to post the script where you declare the screens (I don't even know what navigation library you use yet...).

I also hope that the whitespaces that are present in the <Form  navigation = {this.props.navigation} 
/>
are not in your code, and you have navigation={this.props.navigation} without spaces.

Comment: In App.js  "import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
"

Comment: const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Login,
    navigationOptions: { header: null } 
  },
  HomeScreen : HomeScreen,
},
{
  initialRouteName: "Home"
}
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

Answer (score 0):

I think your onPress function in your *form.js* is not correct.

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}onPress={() => Login(this.state.username,this.state.password,this)}>
```

You should instead have a function that navigate to Login component like

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Login', {username: this.state.username, password: this.state.password})}
```

and pass the *username* and *password* as parameters.

I would also avoid passing *this* to nested components...

Comment: Thanks , but my main problem in Loginapi.js (Script) where after true response I want to navigate to HomeScreen.js